# Regex Expression to capture new lines in a group

Tags: regex, newline, capture, regex-group

I am trying to capture all new lines inside a group.This what I am trying to capture.So I have this string:

```
<span style="color: #00cc00;">1.207.245.184:80
1.234.28.114:80
1.234.28.160:80
1.234.28.18:80
1.234.28.20:80
</span></span></pre>
```

I want to capture the proxies inside a group,but each proxy is on a separate line.How can I do that? I tried this expression but it won't capture all lines.

```
<span style="color: #00cc00;">(.*)(\n.*)
```

This only captures the first proxy and the second one ( on the second line ).

Comment: `/<span style="color: #00cc00;">(.*)<\/span>/g`

Comment: The answer from `user1551066` will return each number as a match, which is good :) My example above will return all inside the `<span>` as a match.

Comment: This is what I initially tried,but it wont find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be this will work:

```
/([\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}:[\d]{2,4})/g
```

Comment: Just FYI: You can write it as `/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d{2,4}/g`.